# Cascading Dropdown Validation: Second dropdown always validates after first is selected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, drop-down-menu

I have a simple set of cascading dropdowns which use jquery to validate.  They are both required.

If you leave them both un-selected and try to submit the form, they will both show as red and the form will not submit.

But, if you select a value in the *first* while leaving the *second* dropdown un-selected, and then submit the form, the form will submit and throw a server-side error because the second dropdown value, which is required, has not been selected.

Here's the (stripped down) HTML with both un-selected:

```
<form action="/Project/ProjectDocumentUpload" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" onsubmit="return Validate('UploadFormModal');">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputType">Phase</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select id="PhaseDD" data-val="true" data-val-required="Select a Phase.">
                <option value="">-Select-</option>
                <option value="1">Planning</option>
                <option value="2">Procurement</option>
                <option value="3">Installation</option>
                <option value="4">Closure</option>
            </select> <span class="required">*</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" style="float:left;">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputType">Process</label>
        <div class="controls ProcessDD">
            <select id="ProjectProcessTypeId" name="ProjectProcessTypeId" data-val="true" data-val-required="Select a Process">
               <option value="">-Select-</option>
           </select> <span class="required">*</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Save changes" class="btn btn-primary disable-button-upon-submit">
    </div>
```

And when I select a value in the first, the only thing that changes is the second dropdown now has values:

```
<select id="ProjectProcessTypeId" name="ProjectProcessTypeId" data-val="true" data-val-required="Select a Process">
    <option>-Select-</option> 
    <option value="1">Kickoff</option> 
    <option value="2">Project Team Selection</option> 
    <option value="3">Define the Work</option>
</select>
```

What am I missing here?  How can I get the second dropdown to validate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  When the second dropdown is populated, this:

```
<option>-Select-</option>
```

Needed to be this:

```
<option value=''>-Select-</option>
```